# Sort iPhone TableView From RSS Alphabetically

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview, rss

I am trying to change my podcast view from sorting via pubDate to sorting alphabetically.  The code used in parsing the RSS currently for dates is:

```
 NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            for (RSSEntryDirectory *entry in entries) {

                int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                    RSSEntryDirectory *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                    RSSEntryDirectory *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                    return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                }];

                [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

            }

        }];
```

How can I change this to just do alphabetically by one of the other entry properties?

Comment: Can't you just modify the line `[entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];` to compare the other property?

Comment: or even you can use any of the `sort` scriptors to sort, while showing in `tableView`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can replace the comparison line:

```
return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
```

by something like that (assuming it is NSString objects):

```
return [entry1.articleTitle localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:entry2.articleTitle];
```